# Three.js updating cube scale with slider variable

Tags: webgl, three.js, jquery-ui-slider

I've created an html page with a jQueryUI slider in one div and a THREE.CubeGeometry in another (see http://codesigntools.com/sample7). The idea is to scale the cube using a global variable (slider1val) which is controlled by the slider. I've looked  [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates) and [here](http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/) but no avail. You can see from the linked code that I'm trying to make changes to the cube within the 'animate' function. Is that right?

I'm pretty new to js and to Three.js but I've used processing quite a bit so maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. Is there an example of someting similar I could look at, or could somebody walk me through the process of accessing and manipulating the cube's size with a global variable?

Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript console (F12) says: `Uncaught ReferenceError: cube is not defined`. The `cube` variable is local to the `init' function, do it global.

Comment: Also if you would like an example of such a thing done successfully with jQuery UI, then you can look at this demo I made up the other day @ --> [Three.JS with jQuery UI Sliders](http://cmg0030.zxq.net/threejs/threeUI)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in the hopes that it will help somebody else:

Both comments were correct:

- I had to define the cube globally and then act on its scale from
  inside my updateGeom() function
- Cory Gross had a good
  example (now a dead link).

For in-depth example, please see on github [here](https://github.com/fabripod/coDesignTools)